# Retrieve array of images from firestore and show them in recycler view

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to retrieve array of images from firestore. I uploaded the images to firebase storage and have added the url to firestore. I can see the card of images in the recycler view but the images are not visible. In Logcat, I get the links of the images which redirect to the images saved in firebase storage. I have attached the adapter class.

```
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class imageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<imageAdapter.holder>
{
    ArrayList<String> imageUrl;
   

    public imageAdapter(ArrayList<String> imageUrl)
    {
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public holder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_image_item,parent,false);
        return new holder(v).linkAdapter(this) ;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull holder holder, int position)
    {
        Glide.with(holder.imageView.getContext()).load(imageUrl).into(holder.imageView);
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount()
    {
        return imageUrl.size();

    }

    class holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        ImageButton imageButton;
        ImageView imageView;
        private imageAdapter imageAdapter;

        public holder(@NonNull View itemView)
        {
            super(itemView);
            imageButton=itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageBtn);
            imageView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    imageAdapter.imageUrl.remove(getAdapterPosition());
                    imageAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(getAdapterPosition());
                }
            });
        }

        public holder linkAdapter(imageAdapter imageAdapter)
        {
            this.imageAdapter = imageAdapter;
            return this;
        }
    }

}
```

MainActivity.java

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResult;
import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultCallback;
import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultLauncher;
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.darsh.multipleimageselect.activities.AlbumSelectActivity;
import com.darsh.multipleimageselect.helpers.Constants;
import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.Query;
import com.marquedo.marquedo.ui.Prod_n_Cat.Product.AboutModelClass;
import com.marquedo.marquedo.ui.Prod_n_Cat.Product.ProductListAdapter1;
import com.marquedo.marquedo.ui.Prod_n_Cat.Product.ProductModelClass;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class update_product extends AppCompatActivity
{

    private String position;
    private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    private EditText category, name, details;

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private AboutModelClass aboutModelClass;
    private MaterialButton add_images_button;
    private imageAdapter imageAdapter;
    private ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> getResult;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_update_product);

        Intent preview = new Intent(this, preview_product.class);
        Button preview_prod = findViewById(R.id.show_preview);
        preview_prod.setOnClickListener(view ->
        {
            startActivity(preview);
        });


        category = findViewById(R.id.prodCategory);
        name = findViewById(R.id.productName);
        details = findViewById(R.id.prodDetails);


        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(null);

        Bundle intent = getIntent().getExtras();
        position = intent.get("key").toString();

        //Getting data from firestore and displaying it on the fields
        db.collection("Store").document("TFTVHvZaHOIxjYLnHvwc").collection("products").document(position).collection("about").document("product_id").get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(@NonNull DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot)
            {
                aboutModelClass = documentSnapshot.toObject(AboutModelClass.class);
        String Category = aboutModelClass.getCategory();
                String Name = aboutModelClass.getName();
                String Details = aboutModelClass.getDetails();

   
                ArrayList<String> Urls = (ArrayList<String>) documentSnapshot.get("Images");
                Log.i("showlist", Urls.toString());
                imageAdapter = new imageAdapter(Urls);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(imageAdapter2);


                
                category.setText(Category);
                name.setText(Name);
                details.setText(Details);
                
            }
        });
       
    }
}
```

ModelClass.java

```
import java.util.List;

public class AboutModelClass
{
    String Category, Details, Name;
    List<String> urls;

    public AboutModelClass()
    {

    }

    public AboutModelClass(String category, String details, String name, List<String> urls) {
        Category = category;
        Details = details;
        Name = name;
        this.urls = urls;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return Category;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        Category = category;
    }

    public String getDetails() {
        return Details;
    }

    public void setDetails(String details) {
        Details = details;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }


    public List<String> getUrls() {
        return urls;
    }

    public void setUrls(List<String> urls) {
        this.urls = urls;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot and indicate the exact images you want to display.

Comment: Got the solution sir.